# How do I log from my map/reduce application?

Tags: logging, hadoop, mapreduce

I would like to use Hadoop's Log4j infrastructure to do logging from my map/reduce application. I think I've got everything set up correctly, 
but I am still unable to specify the logging level I want.

By default, Hadoop is set up to log at level **INFO**.  The first line of its
log4j.properties file looks like this:

```
hadoop.root.logger=INFO,console
```

I have an application whose reducer looks like this:

```
package com.test; public class MyReducer<...> extends Reducer<...> { private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyReducer.class.getName());
    //...    protected void reduce(...) {
       logger.debug("My message");
    //   ...    } }
```

I've added the following line to the Hadoop log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.com.test.MyReducer=DEBUG
```

I expect the Hadoop system to log at level INFO, but my application to log at level DEBUG, 
so that I see "My message" in the logs for the reducer task.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the classloader is finding the log4j.properties file from the Hadoop jars before the one you've modified, so your changes aren't having any effect.  You can specify which log4j configuration file to use by defining the system variable `log4j.configuration`, like this:

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=PATH_TO_FILE
```